# Change string for defiened pattern (Python)

Tags: python, string, replace

Learning Python, came across a demanding begginer's exercise.

Let's say you have a string constituted by "blocks" of characters separated by ';'. An example would be:

> cdk;2(c)3(i)s;c

And you have to return a new string based on old one but in accordance to a certain pattern (which is also a string), for example:

> c?*

This pattern means that each block must start with an 'c', the '?' character must be switched by some other letter and finally '*' by an arbitrary number of letters.

So when the pattern is applied you return something like:

> cdk;cciiis

Another example:

> string: 2(a)bxaxb;ab
>
> pattern: a?*b
>
> result: aabxaxb

My very crude attempt resulted in this:

```
def switch(string,pattern):
d = []
for v in range(0,string):
    r = float("inf")
    for m in range (0,pattern):
        if pattern[m] == string[v]:
            d.append(pattern[m])
        elif string[m]==';':
            d.append(pattern[m])
        elif (pattern[m]=='?' & Character.isLetter(string.charAt(v))):
            d.append(pattern[m])
return d
```

Tips?

Answer (score 0):

- To split a string you can use [split()](https://docs.python.org/fr/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) function.
- For pattern detection in strings you can use regular expressions (regex) with the [re library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).

Comment: How can I use the regular expressions to match patterns?

Comment: you can unse [re.search](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) or [re.match](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match) ([comparaison here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#search-vs-match)) with a pattern corresponding to what you whant to find ([some examples of symbols for patterns here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-regular-expressions)).

Comment: I've tried a simple test: `import re

def switch(s,p):
    d = s.split(';')
    match = re.search(p,d[0])
    return match` and it doesn't work

Comment: It perfectly works when I test your code, can you share what you're using (the string, the pattern, and the expected result) ?

Comment: String: `abc;2(a)2(b)s;a;5(a)` ; pattern: `a?*` ; expected result, because it's d[0]: `abc`

Comment: Error is in your pattern, the `*` only affect the `?`, you should use parenthesis to specify where the `*` have to be applied (`*` creates a recursion, so, on second call, pattern is equal to `?*` that is not possible → something is required before `?`). You can try `(a?)*`.
`abc` can't be matched by `(a?)*`, this pattern can only match strings only mades of `a`. 
If you want to match only letters you can use `[a-z]*` (lowercase letters only) or `([A-Z]+[a-z])*` (for lowercase and uppercase letters).

Comment: You can consult [this table](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html) to found the rights symbols and their use for your pattern

Comment: But like I said in the OP, I have to use the strings and patterns that are given to me, I can't change them. Thanks anyway...

Comment: In the OP you said that `?` has to be switched by "any other letter", this is not what means `?`, so I suppose that you've to modify a little bit the pattern... (anyways, `a?*` is an incorrect pattern). "any letter" can be said with `([A-Z]+[a-z])`, good luck ;)